# Obtener un valor aleatorio a partir de un map con pesos inversos en Java

Tags: java, random, map

Tengo un map del que quiero obtener una palabra para un juego del ahorcado. En el map guardo con cada palabra las veces que ya ha sido elegida. Por ejemplo, el map puede contener:

```
abaleadura  4
abajo 2
abalada 1
abalaustrado 3
```

El map empieza con todas las palabras a cero.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo obtener una palabra aleatóriamente de modo que las que menos hayan aparecido tengan más probabilidad de salir?
He intentado repetir las palabras en una lista y obtener una palabra de esa lista pero tengo problemas para saber las veces que tengo que repetir cada palabra.
Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar el Map común, utiliza el otro tipo llamado TreeMap, donde en este, las claves de los valores se van ordenando automáticamente de menor a mayor.

Una vez que tengas el TreeMap con las palabras, utiliza sobre tu TreeMap el método **firstKey()** para que te devuelva la primera clave en dicho Mapa.

Luego utilizando el método **get(clave)**, que te devolvera el valor de dicha clave.
De esta forma siempre podrás adquirir la palabra que menos apariciones tuvo